# HTTP request with Eureka does not fill port

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, netflix-eureka

I have multiple services running in docker containers through docker-compose.

I am trying to make a http request from one service to another but it fails since the port always gets filled as '80' instead of using the port registered with Eureka.

When I iterate through the discovered applications like so:

```
List<Application> applications = discoveryClient.getApplications().getRegisteredApplications();

   for (Application application : applications) {
       List<InstanceInfo> applicationsInstances = application.getInstances();
            for (InstanceInfo applicationsInstance : applicationsInstances) {

                String name = applicationsInstance.getAppName();
                String url = applicationsInstance.getHomePageUrl();
                System.out.println(name + ": " + url);
            }
        }
```

I get this (correct) output:

```
IDENTITY-SERVICE: http://172.20.0.3:10103/
```

But when the call gets made like this:

```
return webClientBuilder
                    .build()
                    .post()
                    .uri("http://identity-service/api/auth/validate", uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.queryParam("token", "xyz").build())
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(ValidationResponseDTO.class);
```

this exception, indicating that it is calling port 80, is thrown:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: identity-service/172.20.0.3:80
```

When I specify the port ("`http://identity-service:10103/api/auth/validate`") it works perfectly fine.

Anyone have an idea why it is not using the port from Eureka?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing I finally found the solution.

I had not configured the WebClientBuilder correctly. After adding the `LoadBalanced` annotation to the Bean the service name gets correctly resolved.

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder(){
        return WebClient.builder();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

-> The issue you are facing is likely related to how you are constructing the URI for
the HTTP request in your `webClientBuilder`. By default, when using the `uri()`
method with a string argument, the `WebClient` will not take into account the port
specified in the service URL obtained from Eureka, and it will use the default
port, which is **80** for HTTP.

-> Use the `resolve()` method of the URI object to add the **specific path**.

Comment: sadly this does not seem to work. As far as I can tell, uri.resolve() is just used to append a path to a baseurl and has no impact on how the eureka-client name gets resolved.